# How can I install pam_mount on Centos 6 x86_64?

Tags: centos, pam, centos6

I need to use pam_mount to mount user home directories individually at the time that each user logs in. I cant locate a package for this, at least for Centos 6. I would not have a problem building from source if this was a source based distro but because its not I would need to install gcc and all the dependences, seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a RHEL6/CentOS6 pam_mount package [via EPEL](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/pam_mount?_csrf_token=770ec463cdba665258534e06341f74a1db5cba67) soon.

Until then, you can cherry pick [pam_mount and libHX](http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/12/x86_64/) from Fedora 12, as RHEL6 was largely based off of it.

Just grab the packages manually and do a `yum install`.

I went ahead and did this on one of my RHEL6 boxes, as I'm using pam_mount in a few places:

```
# yum install pam_mount-2.5-1.fc12.x86_64.rpm libHX-3.6-1.fc12.x86_64.rpm
```

I went ahead and configured it, and it works perfectly.

Since CentOS aims for 100% binary compatibility with RHEL, it should work fine on your CentOS6 box too.

Comment: Sweet! I tried to do what you describe but when trying to do the yum localinstall I get an error "warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 57bbccba: NOKEY
Public key for pam_mount-2.5-1.fc12.x86_64.rpm is not installed
". Is there a way to install that public key?

Comment: just add `--nogpgcheck`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up finding that in google. I thought it was going to be more complicated then that.

Comment: Did you run into any SELinux issues with pam_mount?

Comment: no, and I am enforcing.  are you seeing issues?

Answer (score 1):

The support matrix says: It does not work right now.

http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/distro-support.php

It seems that you have to wait for a working release. Even installing the compiler toolchain will not help in this case.

Comment: The not so fine print from the top of that page:
"(This page claims neither completeness nor actuality. It will be updated as I see fit, no need to write me.)"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone. I downloaded the Fedora 17 SRPMS for pam_mount and LibHX, did a rpmbuild  and install of LibHX, then pam_mount. The options for the pam_mount.conf.xml are limited, compared to newer OSs. My /etc/secutity/pam_mount.conf.xml mount lines are like:

```
<volume fstype="cifs"  server="fileserver1.foo.com" path="home" mountpoint="~/U" options="dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700,nosuid,nodev"> <not> <uid>0-1024</uid> </not> </volume>
```

I had to tweak /etc/pam.d/password-auth:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        [success=1 default=ignore] pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_deny.so
auth        optional      pam_mount.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
session     optional      pam_mount.so
```

The default "sufficient" on the pam_sss lines will prevent the mounts from occurring.