# Installing pam_mount on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, pam

I'm working on getting a CentOS 5 system that I've successfully gotten to authenticate with AD, to automount the user home directories from AD. After searching around, I found pam_mount, which seemed to be the perfect solution. (The userbase is large enough that there's no feasible way for the automounting to be entirely listed in a file). If there's a better solution, I'm totally open to it.

After much googling, I've yet to find a method to get pam_mount installed on the Centos 5.7 box I'm working on. I looked at [How can I install pam_mount on Centos 6 x86_64?](https://serverfault.com/questions/303203/how-can-i-install-pam-mount-on-centos-6-x86-64), but the RPMs it pointed to just give me dependency errors and won't install. I have, however, found sources talking about having gotten it working. If anyone knows how to get it working from packages, I would greatly appreciate it.

*I know I didn't mention installing from source - we're willing to do it, but we'd like it to be a last resort. It's a campus box, and it needs to be supported for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at http://adminsys.blogspot.com/2011/07/installer-pammount-sur-un-serveur.html - Along with the packages, from Princeton. The blog is in French, but other than a few idioms, it's completely readable.

Those packages install fine, with the dependencies noted, and work.