# pam_mount on CentOS 5 NOT working with Winbind

Tags: active-directory, centos5, winbind

I used the instructions located here: [Installing pam_mount on CentOS 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/359583/installing-pam-mount-on-centos-5)

However, when I add the pam_mount.so entries, and reboot the machine, I cannot log in.  Each time I enter the login and press Enter, the system asks me for the login again, instead of the password.

I cannot use LDAP to connect to Active Directory.  I have to use Winbind.

I need help.